Is it possible to make a clickthrough Tkinter window on MacOS?
I'm working on a app that will create an overlay on your MacOS desktop, and using the overlay module I was able to get a transparent Tkinter window working:
import tkinter as tk
from overlay import Window

win = Window(draggable=False)
label = tk.Label(win.root, text="Window_0")
win.root.attributes('-alpha', 0.1)
win.root.overrideredirect(True)
label.pack()
Window.launch()

However, even when I make it fully transparent, you can't click through the window. So is there a way I can make that possible? I'm also open to other solutions. If there's a way to force the tkinter window to always be the window directly behind the active window, and not be focusable, I could work with it.
Note that this differs from several similar questions in that it is specifically for MacOS.
